# Common `ToMap` method across structs

Tags: go

We have a few structs and we wanted to have a common `ToMap` method that converts the struct to Map. It does by marshaling and unmarshalling to json. But it does not seem to work.

Is it because the `Mappable` struct receives `ToMap()` and it does not have any member attributes? 
If so, is there any way to make `ToMap()` to be received on `Params` struct instead of `Mappable` struct.

I've kept the code below but feel free to edit at https://play.golang.org/p/aDsYxddImxb too

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Mappable struct {}

func (m *Mappable) ToMap() (reqInterface map[string]interface{}) {
    resJson, err := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println("**** err ****", err)
    json.Unmarshal(resJson, &reqInterface)
    return
}

type Params struct {
    Mappable
    A   string `json:"a"`
    B   string `json:"b"`
    C   string `json:"c"`
    D   string `json:"d"`
}

func main() {
    params := Params{
        A: "dummy",
        B: "dummy",
        C: "dummy",
        D: "dummy",
    }
    fmt.Printf("struct to convert: %#v \n", params)
    fmt.Println("Converted with common ToMap method: ", params.ToMap())
}
```

Comment: There is no inheritance and virtual methods in Go. `Mappable.ToMap()` always receives a value of `*Mappable` regardless of where it's embedded. "Childs" don't automatically know about their "parents", you have to take care of that manually. In your case it's easier to just create a utility _function_ instead of a _method_, which may take an `interface{}` value and do what your `Mappable.ToMap()` does.

Comment: Just in case it is not clear what icza means by `utility function`: A function with the signature `func ToMap(s interface{}) (reqInterface map[string]interface{})`. But I'd strongly suggest to first embrace go's intentional lack of inheritance (and this far also of generics) and learn how to write idiomatic Go code. Actually I doubt there is a good reason for a `ToMap` function at all. You are throwing away Go's type system instead of using it.